# How to add message to message table with ID greater than 0x20000000 (bit 29 set)?

Tags: c, winapi

I writing Win32 program using C. I'm using message table to keep all custom defined messages as shown in the following fragment:

```
;#ifndef MESSAGE_H
;#define MESSAGE_H
;

MessageIdTypedef = DWORD

SeverityNames=
    (
        Success         = 0x0:STATUS_SEVERITY_SUCCESS
        Informational   = 0x1:STATUS_SEVERITY_INFORMATIONAL
        Warning         = 0x2:STATUS_SEVERITY_WARNING
        Error           = 0x3:STATUS_SEVERITY_ERROR
    )

FacilityNames =
    (
        System  =0x0:FACILITY_SYSTEM
        Runtime =0x2:FACILITY_RUNTIME
        Stubs   =0x3:FACILITY_STUBS
        Io      =0x4:FACILITY_IO_ERROR_CODE
    )

LanguageNames = 
    (
        English = 0x0409:MSG_EN
        Chinese = 0x0804:MSG_ZH
    )

MessageId       = 1
SymbolicName    = MSG_SUCCESS
Severity        = Success
Language        = English
Success
.
Language        = Chinese
成功
.

MessageId       = +1
SymbolicName    = MSG_OUT_OF_MEM
Language        = English
Out of memory
.
Language        = Chinese
内存不足
.
```

In the program I retrieved these messages using `FormatMessage()` like this:

```
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY, NULL, dwError, LANG_NEUTRAL, (LPTSTR) &lpszTemp, 0, NULL);
```

Where dwError is the `MessageId` in message table.
But [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) said,

> Error codes are 32-bit values (bit 31 is the most significant bit).
>   Bit 29 is reserved for application-defined error codes; no system
>   error code has this bit set. If you define error codes for your
>   application, set this bit to indicate that the error code has been
>   defined by an application and to ensure that the error codes do not
>   conflict with any system-defined error codes.

So I tried change the `MessageId` to starts from 0x20000001, but MC.exe failed me saying

```
Message.mc(29) : error : Message Id value (20000001) too large
```

My question is, how can I add message into message table with properly defined id (bit 29 set)?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: You should really consider using the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS` flag in your call to [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351.aspx). While you are using custom messages, and can - in theory - make inserts work, I don't see any provisions in your sample. In the same vein, the `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY` looks wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `-c` argument for `mc.exe` - this will make it set the "Customer code flag" (bit 29) for all message IDs.

The actual message ID value you specify in the message text file must fit in 16 bits (so in the above example, you would just specify `MessageId=1` and with the -c flag, mc.exe would turn this into `0x20000001`).